# is there anyway to hide swf path?

Tags: php, web, flash

Is there anyway to hide `.swf` path showing up from webpage?

Comment: Hide it from showing up where? In the url? In the html page source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a php script something like getswf.php?name=flash.swf in your flash tags.  Then create getswf.php script to respond with output of flash.swf file, and keep flash.swf file in a directory outside of public directory.

Comment: Yeah I have checked that option but doesnt seems work for .swf file but works for image files

Comment: +1 for a thoughtful answer. Altho if it came to preventing the user from downloading the swf, it would be as easy as if the url contained the actual file.

Comment: I hope so this is the one I used Header("Content-type: application/x-shockwave-flash");

Comment: I am not worried about downloading..but want to hide the actual path. dont assume to something else I never thought off please

Comment: @JCOC611: Okay then also implement a token system.

Comment: @limo: okay well them you will have to show code you used then.  if it "didn't work" then my first thought is that you attempted to output it and the header() in your script that outputs everything else and generated some type of headers already sent error...

Comment: @limo: "dont assume to something else I never thought off please" - okay well this method does work, so if it didn't work for YOU then you did something wrong.  If you don't want me to *assume* what you may or may not have done wrong, then perhaps you can explain what exactly you tried so that I don't have to guess. we're here trying to help you, stop being an ass.

Comment: @crayon Violent I wasnt replying that to you actually that for @JCO611

Comment: I didn't really assume anything, I just pointed out the possibilities, its on your hands if you decide to take my post into account or just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

There may be ways to make it difficult to view.  However, nothing you do can stop an intelligent adversary from using a tool like Fiddler to monitor web traffic and undo all your obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a fairly pointless exercise. Any resource that gets sent to a browser, be it an image, sound, flash movie, even flv files loaded by the YouTube player, can all be saved to disk fairly easily.

As Justin mentions, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) can achieve this easily.

Comment: I strongly believe if you use a server side script like .php to hide a path then client side scripts like fiddler cant find it

Comment: That's where you're wrong. The fact of the matter remains, the end-user will need to navigate to the address of the URL from which he is to view said .swf file. And with that being the case the end-user will always have access to the path to the file being downloaded, the .swf. Unless your server is reading in the source swfs' content and spitting out it's own swf. Other than that there will be no other way you can hide the swf files' path or url.

Comment: Fiddler might not be able to find the physical .swf file on the server, but itcan certainly save the stream of bytes that gets sent to the browser. The only thing you can hope to conceal is the original filename.

Answer (score 0):

As others answered it there are ways to do it using your script. If you are looking for a paid option check this out [Media Vault](http://www.limelightnetworks.com/2009/07/media-vault/).

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the URL to the swf file might be quite a challenge but there are other things you can do if you're wanting to more closely protect the video/data being displayed by the swf.

I'll run through a couple of ideas in the order I think them most obfuscated with the least first. Bare in mind that most of these techniques merely make it harder to get to the information/video rather than making it impossible to obtain.

The main idea most sites tend to follow is that of having the swf as a player and the content in another file somewhere else, usually an flv or mp4 etc.

**Add flv location through Javascript**

This technique is as basic as it sounds. You have your swf player on the page and pass a new variable too it (such as 'file') with the location to the flv file using Javascript. If you're already loading your content with some kind of JS flash module then all the easier to begin implimenting.

**Obfuscating flv location through XML**

Another techniqe I've seen used quite recently is that of having an XML document as a paremeter to the swf player and then the flash player itself resolves the URL of the flv from a node in the XML. It's easy to get to the flv URL if you want to but it does make it that little bit harder.

**Token access**

This technique can be used in conjunction with any of the above two. You basically ensure that your flv files can only be accessed with the use of a special token otherwise the page returns a HTTP error. The token would be understood by the flash player and the server and upon the player making a request for the flv, a token must be included (usuallu the token itself is obfuscated in some way that it cannot be easily mimmicked through a simple GET request).

**Domain access**

Very similar to the above however in this case, the flv file will only be loaded when the requesting URL is a specific site. All other requests will be denied (such as directly hitting the flv location in your browser.

As stated above, none of these methods make it impossible to get hold of your flash material. If it's on the web (or any network for that matter), it's possibly a target. You'll usually find for most things that making it harder to obtain will deter a lot of those who would otherwise have been privy to downloading your content.

**Completely hiding the URL to the swf**

If your only criteria is to hide the URL then hiding it behind a URL rewrite is the best option I can think of.

Your swf might be at `/location/flash/player.swf?file=summer.flv` and then you could do a URL rewrite to something like `/vacations/summer2011/`.

This way the URL to the swf is completely hidden away and this should satisfy your desire to hide the swf path.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO.

You may not want to believe it. but it is a fact. you can do all you like to obfuscate it. but the browser needs to find it. if the browser can find it so can anyone else.

A server side script that acts as a loader will hide the real path to the file, but to what purpose. the end result is the file is still available.

If you want a simple answer, so simple people can't find it then the people here have given you some suggestions. obfuscation is the best you can hope to achieve.

Alternately only allow approved users access to the file. that way they need to log in to get access to it. but if you want it available publicly then its well, public!

DC